# How do I modify multiple vectors based on a condition on either vector?

Tags: matlab, indexing, vectorization, logical-operators

I have two vectors in MATLAB:

```
AA = [1 2 3 5 6 7 100 1 4 5];
BB = [1 100 3 4 5 8 9 10 11 12];
```

Both are the same length.

If the number `100` appears in either vector, I want to replace it with a `0` and the corresponding number in the other matrix (even if this is not `100`) with a `0`.

Desired output:

```
AA = [1 0 3 6 7 0 1 4 5];
BB = [1 0 3 4 5 0 9 10 11 12];
```

I am struggling with a solution, I can was thinking of creating a third vector and trying to use some logical rules but I couldn't seem to get this working.

```
CC = [AA' BB'];
% logical rules here
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the boolean operator `|` (OR) to get the indices:

```
AA = [1 2 3 5 6 7 100 1 4 5];
BB = [1 100 3 4 5 8 9 10 11 12];

ind = AA == 100 | BB == 100;
AA(ind) = 0
BB(ind) = 0
```

Answer (score 3):

If you did create a matrix from the vectors, you could do logical indexing with `any`. This is flexible if you actually have more than 2 vectors:

```
C = [AA; BB]; % Each row is one of the original vectors
C( :, any(C == 100, 1)) = 0;

% C = [ 1     0     3     5     6     7     0     1     4     5
%       1     0     3     4     5     8     0    10    11    12 ]
```